# SQL - load data warehouse dimension table without business IDs?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, star-schema-datawarehouse, kimball

just wanted to see if any others have dealt with this issue and how.

I am building a star schema DW and currently in the process of structuring my dimension tables. Most of them are fine as the descriptions have IDs, for example I have an “action type description” and an “action type ID” which I can use to build my dimActionType dimension.

My issue is some of the description fields don’t have a corresponding business key - so for example I have a “group role” description but no business ID. What would be the best practice in putting this into a DimGroup table? I can select distinct group role into a table with auto increment but how would I then join my fact table to this?

Appreciate any thoughts/ideas

Answer (score 1):

If the "group role description" uniquely identifies a group role then it is the business key - so just treat it as you would any other business key.

Comment: It’s an nvarchar(50) field though so surely I shouldn’t be joining using this?

Comment: No, you add a surrogate key as the pk of the dimension - just as you would with any other dimension

Comment: When I am building my fact table afterwards how would I join to the surrogate key if it only exists in my dimension table and nowhere else? For the other dimensions I am able to build my fact table and then join onto the business keys to bring over the dimension keys

Sorry, first DW build for me so still trying to understand things like this.

Comment: When loading from your source data you lookup the relevant dimension record using the business key, get the SK for that record and use that SK when building your fact table record

Comment: Ok so in this case the “business key” is the nvarchar(50) field (as there is no associated ID with this) - I should use this to join onto the dimension and then bring through the surrogate key? I thought of this but thought performance might be poor joining on text fields

Comment: Performance will be fine, assuming the use of appropriate indexes. Numeric SKs are used to (amongst other reasons) improve performance for analytical queries where you could be joining millions of rows in 1000s of queries per day. Using text fields for joining when data loading doesn't cause an issue, anymore than it does when you are querying a transactional system